# How get value selected using Zend_Form_Element_Select

Tags: zend-form

I have the following code in a Zend form, creating a drop-down list fed from a database:

```
// ... previously create the array $list and fill it from database

$element = new Zend_Form_Element_Select('name');
$element->setLabel('List name')
    ->addMultiOptions($list);   
$this->addElement($element, 'list_name', array(
         'required' => true,
        ));
```

Question: how can I get the value after posting the form?
With the above code, $post['name'] returns the index of the selected item.
A detail: the html generated code shows that the content in the $list are assigned to each element as 'label=' and the 'value=' attribute is the index that I retrieve through $post.
So I believe it's a matter of correctly defining the options of Zend_Form_Element_Select ...

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The $list array should be built as:

```
$list = array(
    'value1' => 'label1',
    'value2' => 'label2',
);
```

After you've called isValid(), you can retrieve the value using `$form->getValue('list_name');`

If, instead, you want to retrieve the label, you can do:

```
$listNameOptions = $form->getElement('list_name')->getMultiOptions();
$label = $listNameOptions[$form->getValue('list_name')];
```

Answer (score 1):

At first,i have the same question as you,then i tried like this,it works:

**create the select obj :**

```
...//code above ellipsis
$userName = new Zend_Form_Element_Select("userName");  //create obj
$userName->setLabel('user');

$db = Zend_Registry::get("db");
$sql = $db->quoteInto('select * from user',null);
$users = $db->query($sql)->fetchAll();

$userArray = array();
foreach ($users as $user){
    /*use value as the key,while form submited,key was added into response obj*/
    $userArray[ $user['name']] = $user['name']; //create the $list
}

$userName->addMultiOptions($userArray);
...
```

**get selected data :**

```
... 

//check if method is post

if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()){  

    $formData = $this->getRequest()->getPost();

    if($loginForm->isValid($formData)){

        //get the selected data

        $userName = $this->getRequest()->getParam('userName'); 
...
```